# Find the most popular in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is

```
f1(drinker,shop)
```

The table has a list of drinkers and the shops which they visit.I need to find the most popular shop.I know I can do a simple group by of shops and order it in a descending way and limit the results to 1 but my doubt is what if two or more shop have the same number of drinkers in that case my query fails.I can't use limit 2 or 3 because I want a general working query and not a one specific to the data.I am running out of ideas.

Note:
Please don't show this way:

```
select shop from f1 group by shop order by count(*) desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, you have to compare the counts.  Not so pretty with a `group by` query:

```
select shop
from f1
group by shop
having count(*) = (select max(cnt)
                   from (select count(*) as cnt
                         from f1
                         group by shop
                        ) s
                   );
```

You could also do this as a subquery:

```
select shop
from f1 join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from f1
      group by shop
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) f1max
group by shop
having count(*) = max(f1max.cnt);
```